# Custom view inside Button

Tags: android

Is there a way to put `custom_view.xml` in a `Button` instead of the title? I want the title of my button to have 2 different strings, both using different fonts. I figure the only way to do this is to have a custom view inside of my button?

**EDIT**

I need to derive from the `Button` component to have the ripple effect when I click on the button. I don't want to use a `FrameLayout` with a touch listener.

**EDIT 2**

Would there be any way to get the shadow/border effect of a button too? I pretty much want to make it look/feel like a natural Android button, with the same look/feel when clicked, but with a custom view inside it.

Comment: _to have the ripple effect_ - You can just use `?selectableItemBackground` as a background on your `FrameLayout` and it will also have a ripple

Comment: You mean like this `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"` ?

Comment: Yes. But you will need a click listener on the view or it won't do anything

Comment: Just to avoid confusion for anyone else reading this, you want to put `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` on the `FrameLayout` and make sure to set a click listener on it, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just take the style of the button and apply it to any ViewGroup. This takes care of most properties (padding, minHeight, background drawable, ripple drawable, elevation when pressed etc.).

For example to make a simple colored button with an icon (style for TextView was changed to match the button style as well):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonViewGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_test"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored"
        android:text="Hallo world!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you are free to set any OnClickListener to LinearLayout and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regular linear/frame/relative layout and style it to look like a button?You can add as many views as u want then. Also as others have mentioned, adding the ripple effect is also possible. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="Click Me" />
```

**Method 2:**

**You have to create a xml file in your drawable resource directory. Create a ripple_effect.xml file and add following code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#f816a463"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f816a463" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Then add background for your button

```
 <Button
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Click Me" />
```