# How do I organize view layers? Placing images above a button

Tags: android, android-layout

I want an image to appear above a button, and still have the button clickable.  I want this because I want the button (eventually have a gradient) to appear in the background, to more clearly indicate that it is a button.  An imageButton does not satisfy my needs as I will actually be having two images "on top" of the button, but for the sake of simplicity and understanding, the attached image only has one.

[image: imageView behind button]

Comment: `Button` is essentially a stylized `TextView`. You can easily make a "button" with custom layout [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48452549/9241978).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the problem, here's what I'm assuming you've tried:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <Button/>
    <ImageView/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And I'm betting that you're seeing the `Button` floating "above" the `ImageView`. Maybe you already know this, but that's because buttons have `elevation` by default and images don't.

I think the best course of action would be to **not** try to fight the Android framework here. You *could* add elevation to your image to make sure it was "above" the button, but I think you're better off just playing by the rules of the game.

You can use a [`LayerDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable) to merge many images/drawables into one. Combining e.g. insets and shapes you could have multiple images + gradients all inside a single LayerDrawable, and then you could use this single drawable inside an `ImageButton`.

For example, here's a LayerDrawable that's a gradient + two little androids:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient"/>

    <item
        android:right="32dp"
        android:bottom="32dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_one"/>

    <item
        android:top="32dp"
        android:left="32dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_one"/>

</layer-list>
```

And I can use it in an ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/layer_drawable"/>
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need!  How would I go about changing the layer-list programmatically? Also where did the tag "layer_drawable" come from?

Comment: @microflakes Check the javadoc I linked for `LayerDrawable`. You can create them in java and add layers programmatically. The tag `layer_drawable` just comes from the fact that the `<layer-list>` XML I posted is in `res/drawable/layer_drawable.xml`